# Greater than or not equal to

Tags: javascript

My code here

```
if (parent4 && parent5 && parent6 && (_state[tree][parent4]) + (_state[tree][parent5]) + (_state[tree][parent6]) !== 8) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

It works, and has some of the elements I want, namely that if the sum of the three `_states !== 8`, it returns `false`.

I'll try to explain the logic I'm trying to achieve as simply as I can:

```
if par4 + par5 + par6 !>= 8
  return false

if par4 + par5 !>= 8
  return false

if par4 OR par5 OR par6 !>= 8
  return false

else
  return true
```

I abbreviated the code for simplicity and ease of understanding.

Swapping around `return false` and `return true` and changing it to `>=` doesn't work, because for all elements, even ones I don't mention here, it needs to go to `return true` by default.

Comment: Entire expression in single parentheses -> `(_state[tree][parent4] + _state[tree][parent5] + _state[tree][parent6]) !== 8`

Comment: greater than or not equal to???? so would just be `>`

Comment: I'll rephrase sorry, not greater than or equal to so to write it out !>= 8  it should return false, else return true.

Comment: `if par4 + par5 !>= 8` what would `!>= 8` mean? "Not greater or equal to"? Because that  is "less than". If it's "not equal AND greater or equal" then that's just "greater than".

Comment: That makes some sense, however replacing the "!==" with "greater than" doesn't seem to work. Then it returns false whenever the sum is "greater than" I need it return true whenever the sum is "greater than" and in all other cases.

Comment: OK, I still don't understand what `!>= 8` should be then. You're saying that it should be true if it's greater than 8. Then What *isn't* valid? Less than 8? Only 8?

Comment: No matter how dumb it sounds, I had a really hard time understanding the logic of the different operators, the "less than" is what I need, I just need to set the state of everything to 0 before its passed to the if statement then it works exactly as I want it to. So thanks for your answers it gave me some different perspectives, and helped me move on!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if (parent4 && parent5 && parent6) {
    if ((_state[tree][parent4] + _state[tree][parent4] + _state[tree][parent4]) !== 8) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or in a one-liner:

```
if (parent4 && parent5 && parent6 && (_state[tree][parent4] + _state[tree][parent4] + _state[tree][parent4]) !== 8) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the oneliner what OP already has but with the brackets placed differently (which wouldn't affect the logic)?

Comment: You're right. I wouldn't think it should affect anything. Actually not sure why the OP code isn't working.